# Could i build a mining rig with these parts?

Tags: mining-setup, cpu-mining, mining-hardware, gpu-mining, gpu

I have researched bitcoin mining for a while, and i have decided that i want to build a dedicated miner. Since i am very low on budget, I thought that maybe i could use an old computer that i have in my house for the motherboard and CPU requirements, and by only a GPU. My old computer has an AsusTek computer inc P5S800-VM motherboard, featuring an Intel Pentium 4 processor. Link:
http://www.asus.com/Motherboard/P5S800VM/

Is there a way to add an ATI GPU to this system and make it work as a miner? Thanks for any responses, and sorry if i was not clear enough - i am quite new to this field.

Answer (score 3):

I have to say you did not research Bitcoin mining enough. Mining on a GPU is obsolete, reports say ASIC-based mining devices with x40 the performance have already started shipping.

Comment: As i have said, my budget is very limited and i would prefer to use mostly computer parts that i already have instead of buying new expensive hardware.

Comment: @arielschon12 you might desire being able to fly, but it won't happen anyway. GPU mining is going to be obsolete soon, so you'd likely be mining at a loss.

Comment: Ok then, so would you recommend any butterfly labs products? Or do you know perhaps another ASIC-based mining devices?

Comment: @arielschon12: http://www.avalon-asics.com/ seem to be the winning horse in this race, but I'm not sure they're accepting new orders currently. At this point in time I can't recommend any of the vendors - but I can recommend not buying a GPU for mining as it will almost certainly cause you to lose money.

Comment: Unless you have access, somehow, to free electricity (like, say, using a currently-unused solar panel - please don't think of illegal ways to get it for free) you wouldn't be recovering your costs. You could still buy a GPU and set it to mine Litecoins instead, though - mining them is much CPU and old-machines' friendly

Answer (score 3):

First the bad news: your Motherboard appears not to have a PCI-E Slot, which is required to fit any modern GPU. On the other hand for the price of a single GPU you can order more than 1 ASIC miner with lower power consumption, i.e., cheaper to run, and more computational power.

I'd wait until the first ones actually ship, though.